# how to use incremental imports with --last-value stored in sqoop metastore

Tags: sqoop

Until now, I have been using import command to import data and have been saving --last-value in the default metastore.

1. What to specify for --last-value initially in the import command for incremental import based on last modified value. I see it's 0 for append mode but what should that be in lastmodified mode?
2. I have a table I need to import data incrementally from but the modified_at field of this table is stored in another table referenced via foreign key. Now, since there are multiple tables involved here, I understand that I will need to use free query form but how exactly does it fetch --last-value from metastore? I of course am not going to hard code the last value in free query.

Also, how do I provide modified_at column from this referenced table?

What should be the exact syntax in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Incremental data fetch depends on the primary key and primary key always be in incremental format. You can create a Sqoop job with the import command and give --last-value argument as the value of last primary key value of your table

```
sqoop job --create Job_name -- import --connect "jdbc_url" --username "uid" -P --table "table_name" --check-column "primary-key column" --incremental append --last-value 0 --target-dir /hdfs_path
```

By Doing

```
sqoop job --list
```

You can see the list of jobs created. You can run the job by

```
sqoop job --exec jobname
```

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT HELPS!!!!

Comment: Incremental data doesn't depends on primary key. It only depends on Date orTimestamp.

Comment: If table doesn't have any time stamp column, then how the increment will work then?

Comment: Data Fetch only depends on timestamp not on primary key. So check column must be a timestamp or Date not necessarily primary key!